How many 6awg THHN wires can be run in a V700 Wiremold and be NEC compliant?
I'm helping someone install a level 2 EV charger. We are hardwiring it with three runs of 6 awg THHN from the panel to the garage (black, red, and green as a ground per manufacturer instructions). For aesthetic reasons in his family room he ran 16' of V700 Wiremold raceway along the baseboard to enclose the THHN and then 1" pvc conduit for the rest of the run through a crawlspace. The concern I have is with the Wiremold raceway. NEC guidelines indicate a fill rate of not more than 40% and require the metal raceway be grounded. So far, so good. Using the published dimensions for the V700 (21/32" x 3/4") we calculate the raceway to have .492 square inches of area. Fill tables indicate the #6 THHN is .0507 sq.in. or.152 sq.in for all three wires which is well under the 40%. But visually it looks tight. Does this seem right?

Why are you running 6/3 to an EV charger? Most level 2 chargers just need 240 volts and do not require a neutral especially one that would be full size.

@ArchonOSX  I think OP is using /3 to include ground.  At the bottom says all three wires.  2 hots and ground maybe?  Cable /3 is plus ground.  THHN /3 would include ground

@crip659 They probably bought a charger with a 14-50 plug on the end or something with 4 blades and they think the charger needs a neutral. The Clipper Creek I have had that kind of plug too. But if you open it up and check the wiring the neutral is not being used. You can just hard wire it without the neutral or the range plug. They sell these chargers with that type of plug to make it easy to plug in to an existing receptacle. They are not needed.

Only run two #6 THHN and run a bare #10 ground wire.   That's going to help with fill.
EVs do not use neutral.  Mind you, many EV novices think NEMA 14-50 sockets are the way to hook up charge stations (no), and if you do that, you need a neutral for the socket.  But don't do that lol.
Also if they are into aesthetics, the socket is useless clutter.

Thanks, Harper! I edited my question to clarify that we are hardwiring the charger with three runs of 6 AWG THHN - black, red, and green as a ground - no plug!

BTW - since we ran an insulated ground can we bond it to the metal Wiremold in order to ground it per NEC guidelines?

Part of Harper's answer is that the green 6 can be (a) 10 instead of 6 (cheaper and, more importantly, physically smaller) and (b) bare instead of insulated. As an example (at Home Depot, likely not the cheapest place, but easy to find pricing online): 6 AWG green $ 1.42 per foot, 10 AWG green $ 0.78 per foot, 10 AWG bare $ 0.60 per foot.

Great suggestion! Unfortunately, we already bought the 6 AWG as a ground and are running two Wiremold raceways to solve the possible fill problem.

TWO Wiremold raceways? All wires in a circuit must be together in the same raceway. Only exception is a retrofit ground, which does not apply to a new circuit.

OOPS! Thanks for that info! We can redo into one raceway. Just thought it was safer with lower fill.

@HoneyDo well the ground could be in the other raceway.   I urge people to buy the wire last, after all investigation is complete.

@HoneyDo You must ground the Wiremold, even if there is an insulated ground wire. If you don’t, a live wire could touch it, electrify the whole setup, and present a lethal hazard to anyone who comes in contact.

I cannot find  a wire fill chart for V700 that includes #6 awg, but a ground wire is not required. (See edit below)

250.118 Types of Equipment Grounding Conductors
(A) Permitted. Each equipment grounding conductor run with or enclosing the circuit
conductors shall be one or more or a combination of the following:
(14)Surface metal raceways listed for grounding.

And from LeGrande:

Legrand Wiremold 500 and 700 Series Surface Raceway and Fittings are
listed with UL (RJBT.E4376 and RJPR.E41751) and comply with all the
requirements of Article 386 of the NEC. The 500 and 700 Series Surface
Raceway and Fittings and have been tested and evaluated to UL 5 -
Standard for Surface Metal Raceways and Fittings. The raceway and
fittings may be utilized as an Equipment Grounding Conductor in
compliance with Article 250.118(14). The raceway and fittings comply
with Section 11 of UL 5, which covers Grounding and Bonding
requirements...

Edit: The Wiremold Selection Guide gives the internal capacity as 0.26in². That means 40% for 3 wires would be 0.104, so  0.152 exceeds capacity. The two wire fill only allows 31% fill, 31% of 0.26in² would be 0.0806in², so two wires doesn't meet legal fill either.
So next question, do the instructions specify #6? Or is it a 40A station, requiring 125% circuit breaker, with #8 THHN meeting the 50A requirement?

Thank you for your edit and the info you provided. I tried to find the actual internal capacity of the V700 but couldn't find it on the Wiremold website. So I estimated it - a poor estimate!. We need #6 in order to deliver 48 amps on a 60 amp circuit. I think we're going to follow Harper's recommendation and replace the #6 THHN ground with a bare #10. We'll still be tight with the V700 but will resize the raceway if necessary.
